# Displaying return as text

Tags: javascript, html

I have some functions and some variables. I would like to return a variable and the function outcome as text on my browser.

What I have done is I have made a HTML file with the text:

```
<SCRIPT SRC="rockpaper.js">
</SCRIPT>
```

And this refers to this javascript file:

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "Computer chooses rock";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "Computer chooses paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "Computer chooses scissors";
}

console.log(computerChoice);

var compare = function(choice1,choice2)
{
    if(choice1===choice2)
    {
        return("The result is a tie!");
    }

    if(choice1==="Computer chooses rock")
    {
        if(choice2==="scissors")
        {
            return("rock wins");
        }
            else
            {
                return("paper wins");
            }
    }
    if(choice1==="Computer chooses paper")
    {
        if(choice2==="rock")
            return("paper wins");
            else
            {
                return("scissors wins");
            }
    }
    if(choice1==="Computer chooses scissors")
    {
        if(choice2==="rock")
        {
        return("rock wins");
        }
        else
        {
            return("scissors wins");
        }
    }
}

console.log(compare(computerChoice,userChoice))
```

However, when I open it with a browser, the text doesn't display, but the prompt does.

It works fine in Codecademy, though.

Comment: It may not matter, but you may need a semi-colon at the end of your last line? If you are using chrome, or firefox+firebug press F12 on your keyboard to open the console and check for errors.

Comment: That doesn't seem to help with my problem.

Comment: It's the stuff that's in the console that I want displayed on the webpage itself.

Comment: 'Java' is to 'JavaScript' as 'Car' is to 'Carpet'.

Comment: Hate to say it people, but the keyword is "codeCademy". Doesn't anyone watch the Colbert Report? The example is part of one of their javascript exercises. The real problem is the site does not discuss forms, divs, html elements, or anything that resembles real life. So, what Bjarni is essentially asking is how to display the return and console statements... and the short answer would be to convert them to divObj.innerHTML = whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/7DDLs/) that logs data to the screen. I noticed your tie logic is flawed. You are cheking a big-ass string to the users simple one-word string. You need to tokenize; extract the state from the computer choice string.

**Javascript**

```
// Helpful utility function...
function logResultToScreen(result) {
    var block = document.createElement('div');
    var text = document.createTextNode(result);
    var output = document.getElementById('output');

    block.appendChild(text);
    output.insertBefore(block);
}


var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();

if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "Computer chooses rock";
} else if (computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "Computer chooses paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "Computer chooses scissors";
}

console.log(computerChoice);
logResultToScreen(computerChoice);

var compare = function (choice1, choice2) {
    var tokens = choice1.split(' ');

    if (tokens[2] === choice2) {
        return ("The result is a tie!");
    }

    if (choice1 === "Computer chooses rock") {
        if (choice2 === "scissors") {
            return ("rock wins");
        } else {
            return ("paper wins");
        }
    }
    if (choice1 === "Computer chooses paper") {
        if (choice2 === "rock") {
            return ("paper wins");
        } else {
            return ("scissors wins");
        }
    }
    if (choice1 === "Computer chooses scissors") {
        if (choice2 === "paper") {
            return ("scissors wins");
        } else {
            return ("rock wins");
        }
    }
}

var output = compare(computerChoice, userChoice);
logResultToScreen(output);
console.log(output);
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="output"><strong>Results:</strong></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your using console.log() so you should see output in the developer console (press F12 and open console tab).

To put it on the page, you have to create a DOM(html) element and add it to the page.

```
<SCRIPT SRC="rockpaper.js">
</SCRIPT>
<div id="container"></div>
```

in your script replace

```
 console.log(compare(computerChoice,userChoice))
```

with

```
 var container = document.getElementById("container");
 container.innerHTML = compare(computerChoice,userChoice);
```

Happy coding!